# After upgrading Debian Bullseye to Bookworm, problems with Wordpress and PHP

Tags: php, debian, wordpress

OS: **Debian Bookworm**,
WordPress: **6.2**,
PHP: **8.2**

I upgraded my webserver from Debian Bullseye to Bookworm today. Everything worked - except all Wordpress sites. When visiting such a site (on my server), I first got the following error message:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Please check that the mysqli PHP extension is installed and enabled.
```

I knew my PHP was upgraded from v7.4 to v8.2 so I thought installing the mysql extension for 8.2 would solve the problem:

```
apt-get install php8.2-mysql
```

Some Wordpress sites now worked, others were giving this error:

```
There has been a critical error on this website.
```

So no idea where to go from here... Can anybody give me some pointers? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I activated debug mode on one of the non-working sites, and the debug log showed this:

```
[25-Jul-2023 14:07:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError:
call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback,
non-static method MerlicFilterCategoryLite::filter() cannot be called
statically in /usr/sites/asite/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308

Stack trace:
#0 /usr/sites/asite/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the problem is caused by plug-ins which are not compatible with PHP 8.2.

To solve:

**1) Disable all plugins**

If you are unable to open your WP dashboard in a browser, connect to your server either using SSH or FTP. Next, go to your *wp-content* folder. Rename your *plugins* folder to *plugins.old*. You should now be able to load your site's dashboard in your browser again. Rename the *plugins.old* folder back to *plugins*. Your plugins are now all disabled.

**2) Update all your plugins**

In your WP dashboard, click *Plugins* in the left menu. Update any plugin that needs updating *without activating it yet*.

**3) Enable plugins one by one**

After all plugins are updated, enable them one by one, reloading the page after each plugin you enable. If you get an error message after enabling a plugin, you know that plugin is causing the problem. Move that plugin out of the *plugins* folder on your server. Check all plugins for problems in the same way.